# Sample.Split in R SplitRatio parameter has to be i [0,1]

Tags: r

I am getting the following error:

> Error in sample.split: 'SplitRatio' parameter has to be i [0, 1] range or [1, length(Y)] range

when I try to run the following code:

```
set.seed(1000)
library(caTools)
split = sample.split(letters$isB, SplitRatio = 0.5)
```

Comment: Great. What's your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How do I get this function to work? My syntax does not appear to be incorrect.

Comment: Beats me. It'd be a lot easier to diagnose if it were reproducible, but `letters$isB` is not valid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Make sure you've dropped or omitted all NA values so that you have same vector length. This will also cause this error.

Answer (score 10):

There is nothing wrong with the syntax. You probably spelled your outcome variable (letters$isB) incorrectly. Since letters$isB does not exist (or not loaded), you get that error.

Answer (score 1):

I received an error similar to what was listed above. I realized that I had forgotten to change my variable in the code listed below

```
split = sample.split(dataset$Profit,
```

from profit to units sold (variable in my actual data set) vs. profit which was code from another project. Hope this helps - I listed the rest of my code and my errors below.

```
> library(caTools)
> set.seed(123)
> split = sample.split(dataset$Profit, SplitRatio = .8)
Error in sample.split(dataset$Profit, SplitRatio = 0.8) : 
  Error in sample.split: 'SplitRatio' parameter has to be i [0, 1] range or [1, length(Y)] range
> training_set = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)
Error in split == TRUE : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
> test_set = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)
Error in split == FALSE : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `letters$isB` length is 0?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35706404/6188234)

"maybe letters$isB length is 0?"

makes sense with more context. In my experience with another MOOC I received this error, and came to SO looking for an answer.

After referring to [Sample.split in R - SplitRatio parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257487/sample-split-in-r-splitratio-parameter)

I noted that the error is generated if the variable you are trying to split doesn't exist - because of a typo. So the error message misleads the coder to look at the SplitRatio Constant, instead of the variable you are splitting.

split = sample.split(letters$THISDOESNOTEXIST, SplitRatio = 0.5)

In my case this typo was the camelCase of the variable name, so it was difficult to seethe syntax error. Fixing that type cleared this error.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, and I am sure nothing is wrong with the syntax nor with the variables. 
More interestingly, the code works if I run the related chunk manually on Rmarkdown, but when I run the whole markdown from top to bottom, it returns error.

Answer (score 0):

`set.seed(1000)
library(caTools)
split = sample.split(letters$isB, SplitRatio = 0.5)`

isB should be the label of the Dependent variable, look up in your dataset that name.

[Here](https://github.com/cran/caTools/blob/master/R/sample.split.R) you can find why this error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Make sure you've dropped or omitted all your NA values.